# Traversing through the AST node

Tags: java, eclipse-plugin

i want to find out the line number where a call is referenced using AST api in a package.
How can i do that?

Comment: i have compilation unit from project. now i want to search for a particular method reference in this unit usint AST (abstract syntax tree) api

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have an illustration on how to search within the method of a CompilationUnit in this [papercut article](http://www.vogella.de/blog/2009/07/15/find-unused-methods/):

```
for (ICompilationUnit unit : mypackage.getCompilationUnits()) {
IType[] types = unit.getTypes();
for (int i = 0; i < types.length; i++) {
  IType type = types[i];
  IMethod[] methods = type.getMethods();
```

- If the method is an [ASTNode](http://kickjava.com/src/org/eclipse/jdt/core/dom/ASTNode.java.htm), you can use the `ASTNode.getStartPosition()` function.
- If the compilation unit of that IMember is a [`CompilationUnit`](http://kickjava.com/src/org/eclipse/jdt/core/dom/CompilationUnit.java.htm), you can use that in the `CompilationUnit.getLineNumber(position)`

Comment: are you sure its getoccurencecount to get position?

Answer (score 2):

CompilationUnit.getLineNumber(int position)

position is relative to the CompilationUnit object

Documentation:

> Returns the line number corresponding
>   to the given source character position
>   in the original source string. The
>   initial line of the compilation unit
>   is numbered 1, and each line extends
>   through the last character of the
>   end-of-line delimiter. The very last
>   line extends through the end of the
>   source string and has no line
>   delimiter. For example, **the source
>   string class A\n{\n} has 3 lines
>   corresponding to inclusive character
>   ranges [0,7], [8,9], and [10,10].**
>   Returns -1 for a character position
>   that does not correspond to any source
>   line, or -2 if no line number
>   information is available for this
>   compilation unit.

Comment: how am i supposed to know the method's position?

Comment: position is relative to the CompilationUnit.

Comment: i need actual line number in source file

Comment: position (the parameter) is relative to the CompilationUnit, but the result (return value) is absolute to the file.

Comment: Didn't see your answer at the time. +1